# Trying to understand negation of quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers, quantifier-elimination

Trying to understand the negation of the following:

For this:
∀x~P(x)
I have this as negation:
~∃xP(x)

For this:
~∃x(∀yP(y) Λ Q(x))
I have this:
∀x(~∃yP(y) V ~Q(x))

Are these correct? If not please provide the right negation

Moving the negation signs:

∃x~P(x) ☰ ~∃xP(x)?

∀x(~∃yP(y) V ~Q(x)) ☰ ∀x~(∀yP(y) Λ Q(x)) ☰ ~∃x(∀yP(y) Λ Q(x))??

Are the above still equivalent?

Comment: The negations are correct.

Comment: @HassanMuhammad
I added more to the above, is it still correct?

Comment: The first one is not correct.

Comment: Clearly, $\exists x (\neg Px)$ and $\neg (\exists x Px)$ are **not equivalent**. Besides, since we have the **unique parsing theorem** for FOL, the **scope** of both quantifiers, negation and others operators must **always** be taken into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall x.\neg P(x)$ and $\neg \exists x.P(x)$ are *not* each other's negations -- on the contrary they are *equivalent*.

If you negate $\forall x.\neg P(x)$ you get either $\neg\forall x.\neg P(x)$ which is equivalent to $\exists x.P(x)$.

---

$\exists x.\neg P(x)$ is *not* equivalent to $\neg\exists x.P(x)$.

$\exists x.\neg P(x)$ *is* equivalent to $\neg\forall x.P(x)$. When you move a negation through a quantifier, the quantifier changes from $\exists$ to $\forall$ or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Informally, $\forall x(\lnot P(x))$ precisely  if $\exists x P(x)$. So $\exists xP(x)$ is a correct negation of  $\forall x(\lnot P(x))$

More formally, $\lnot\forall x\varphi$ if and only if $\exists x(\lnot\varphi)$.  Using $\varphi=\lnot P(x)$, we get $\lnot\lnot P(x)$, or equivalently $P(x)$.

The second is simpler. If you want to negate $\lnot\exists x(\forall yP(y)\land Q(x))$, you just remove the $\lnot$ in front.

**Remark:** It is not clear what you are asking for the second problem, for negating  $\lnot\exists x(\forall yP(y)\land Q(x))$ is perhaps too simple to be asked as a question. If you want to negate $\exists x(\forall yP(y)\land Q(x))$, the first step is to write $\forall x(\lnot (\forall yP(y)\land Q(x))      )$. Then if we feel like it we can replace $\lnot (\forall yP(y)\land Q(x))$ by 
$(\lnot \forall yQ(y))\lor (\lnot Q(x))$, and then if we wish replace $\lnot\forall yQ(y)$ by $\exists y\lnot Q(y)$.

Comment: I edited the question again, can you check and see if it is still correct?

Comment: Your second sentence is not right. The sentences $\forall x(\lnot P(x))$ and $\lnot\exists x(P(x))$ are *equivalent*, one is not equivalent to the negation of the other.